# Creating a good mysql schema for web front end usage

Tags: mysql

I have recently started working with a company who sends me data via JSON, the JSON looks like this:

```
[{
        "name": "company1",
        "dataset": null,
        "data": [{
                "x": "2015-01-01T00:00",
                "y": 182
            },
            {
                "x": "2015-01-02T00:00",
                "y": 141
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "company2",
        "dataset": null,
        "data": [{
                "x": "2015-01-01T00:00",
                "y": 182
            },
            {
                "x": "2015-01-02T00:00",
                "y": 141
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "company3",
        "dataset": null,
        "data": [{
                "x": "2015-01-01T00:00",
                "y": 182
            },
            {
                "x": "2015-01-02T00:00",
                "y": 141
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I get 57 of these daily (Almost identical with the only difference being that the Y value changes accoridng to which metric it is) one for each metric tracked by the company. As you can see the way in which they've written the JSON (X & Y Key value pairs) make it rather hard to store nicely.

I've made 57 tables in MySQL, one for each JSON that inserts the values for that specific metric however querying to get all activity for a day takes a LONG time due to the amount of joins.

I'm hoping one of you might be able to tell me the best way in whihc to insert this into a mysql db table for where I end up either 1 table containing all 57 values or the best way to query across 57 tables without waiting hours for mysql to load it.

this is a personal project for my own business so funds are tight and I am doing what I can at the moment - sorry if this sounds ridiculous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to be required to store this data, I would personally be inclined to use a table for all the results, with a company table holding the 'master' information about each company.

The `company` table would be structured like this:

```
id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(50) -- Arbitrary size - change as needed
```

The `company_update` table would be structured like this:

```
company_update_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
company_id        INT NOT NULL,
update_timestamp  DATETIME,
update_value      INT -- This may need to be another type
```

There would be a foreign key between `company_update.company_id` to `company.company_id`.

When receiving the JSON update:

1. Check that the name exists in the `company` table.  If not, create it.
2. Get the company's unique ID (for use in the next step) from the `company` table.
3. For each item in the `data` array, add a record to `company_update` using the appropriate company ID.

Now in order to get results for all companies, I would just use a query like:

```
SELECT  c.name,
        cu.update_timestamp,
        cu.update_value
  FROM  company c
    INNER JOIN company_update cu ON cu.company_id = c.company_id
  ORDER BY c.name, cu.update_timestamp DESC
```

Note that I have made the following assumptions which you may need to address:

- The company name size is at most 50 characters
- The `y` value in the `data` array is an integer

Comment: Hi Martin! thank you for such a prompt and extremely detailed answer! Your assumptions (to date) are all true and the explanation you provided seems extremely logical. I will implement this and see how it goes! Thanks once again!